# CQ5 combobox-selection get value not title

Tags: jsp, combobox, dialog, aem

I have a widget of

```
   <orderBy
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldDescription="Select a property to sort results. Ordered by 'Title' as default."
    fieldLabel="Order by"
    name="./orderBy"
    type="combobox"
    xtype="selection">
    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <title
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="Title"
        value="jcr:title"/>
        <author
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="Author"
        value="jcr:created"/>
        <modified
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="Date Modified"
        value="cq:lastModified"/>
        <activated
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="Activation Date"
        value="cq:lastReplicated"/>
        <offtime
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="Off Date"
        value="offTime"/>
        <owner
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="Owner"
        value="jcr:contentOwner"/>
        <confidentiality
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="Confidentiality"
        value="confidentialityCode"/>
    </options>
</orderBy>
```

When the user uses the dropdown they see the text field in the options (as expected) but when I go to fetch the selected item from the jsp I want to get the value.  Currently I am doing:

```
String selectedItem = (String) properties.get("dropDownSel", "");
```

What do I have to do to get the value instead of the text property?

Comment: Looks, like you are doing it right. So it should work. Can you post xml presentation of your dialog?

Comment: The string being returned is the text, not the value.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong combination of type and xtype, so wrong field has been saved to property.

If you change type of your widget from **combobox** to **select** it will be saving **value** to property instead of **text** and you will solve your problem.

**UPD 1**
So I created next dialog, it opens and save **value** as it should.
The only difference with your - is changed type of widget to **select**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
xtype="tabpanel">
<items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
    <mainPanel
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        title="Main panel"
        xtype="panel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <orderBy
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                fieldDescription="Select a property to sort results. Ordered by 'Title' as default."
                fieldLabel="Order by"
                name="./orderBy"
                type="select"
                xtype="selection">
                <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <title
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    text="Title"
                    value="jcr:title"/>
                    <author
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    text="Author"
                    value="jcr:created"/>
                    <modified
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    text="Date Modified"
                    value="cq:lastModified"/>
                    <activated
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    text="Activation Date"
                    value="cq:lastReplicated"/>
                    <offtime
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    text="Off Date"
                    value="offTime"/>
                    <owner
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    text="Owner"
                    value="jcr:contentOwner"/>
                    <confidentiality
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    text="Confidentiality"
                    value="confidentialityCode"/>
                </options>
            </orderBy>
        </items>
    </mainPanel>
</items>
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it wont open the editor at all.  This indicates something is wrong.  According to this doc, the xtype should be selection not type: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/widgets/xtypes.html

Comment: Yes, definitely something is wrong. Because approach I wrote perfectly works on my local instance. If you post  code for your dialog here, probably, I will be able to help you with this.

Comment: I've added this to the Question

Answer (score -1):

The issue was the type was combobox.

I would imagine this stems from the combobox having the option for manual input, thus it would have to get the text field of every element as opposed to its value.